# How to connect as different user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How do I connect as different user in MySQL. When I start MySQL command line I am prompted to enter the password for root. I have tried the following command to connect as a user I created but when I press enter I am taken to a new line without asking me for password:

```
mysql -h localhost -u user1 -p
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
>> mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

replace USERNAME with the username you created and then press enter. You should be prompted for the password.